# How should I extract nested list for saving to database?

Tags: python, sql, google-sheets, sqlalchemy

**Exception:**

```
Unpack operation not allowed in this context
```

**My code for doing it:**

```
def save_data_to_database(self):
    parsed_records = self.parse_sheet_data()
    for record in parsed_records:
        self.db.set_item(
            "sheet", #table name
            "id, number_of_order, cost, delivery_time" # These are fields in table
            f"{*record}" # Here I'm trying to unpack values, but I can't
        )
```

**Value of 'parsed_records' looks like:**

```
[['1', '1249708', '675', '24.05.2022'], ['2', '1182407', '214', '13.05.2022'], ['3', ...]]
```

*If you see code in above, I want to unpack record with " * " but I can't.*
**What should I do for saving records to db?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this solve your problem

“,”.join(record)

Comment: Thanks for a time that you spent! I found solution with 
"{} '{}' {} '{}'".format(*record)